# Why is the test statisic for the absence of correlation $t=\frac{b_{1}}{s/\sqrt{S_{xx}}}$

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

I am trying to understand the test for absence of correlation. I would like to understand why the test statistic is given in the following manner:

[image]

In the case of corelation it is
[image]

Could the reason be that the distribution for $b_{1}=$correlation coefficient

[image]

Is difficult to figure out, so instead $r$ is expressed in terms of t, so that the (known)distribution of t can be used?

I would really appreciate some tips. I have gone through many books and I couldn't find any explanation as to why the statstic is the way it is.

Answer (score 1):

The above test statistic is actually used to test whether the true *regression* coefficient ($\beta_1$) is different from zero. You can still use this to test whether the *correlation* coefficient ($\rho$) is different from 0 by noting that $\rho > 0 \iff \beta_1 > 0$ and $\rho < 0 \iff \beta_1 < 0$.

If you want to test whether the true correlation is different from another value, say $\rho = 0.4$, you have to use a different test statistic from the one above. In this case you need an arctanh transform to obtain a usable test statistic, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_transformation. Note that this procedure relies on the assumption that the response and covariates follow a bivariate normal distribution.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I realised I am actually interested in why the test statistic is taken to be in standadized form, i.e. why the first equation is used.

Comment: @Hans In this case, it is possible to deduce that by using the above expression, the test statistic follows a t-distribution with $n-2$ degrees of freedom under standard assumptions for the simple linear regression model. A similar expression also yields a valid test statistic for the intercept.

Comment: That it follows a t-distribution is fine. What I don't understand is why the test statistic is not taken to be (sample statist - null paramter). In other words why is it standardized.

Comment: It wouldn't follow a t-distribution if it was not standardised; the distribution of you proposed test statistic depends on the variance of the residuals, which is unknown. By standardising, the test statistic no longer depends on any unknown quantities.

Comment: So whats happening is a transformation of a random variable to another random variable of which we know the distribution and are therefor able to calculate probabilities? If I look at the transform rv T I can calculate a critical value etc. . But since I am interested in, say r,  am I not interested to know for which critical value c I have something like $0.05=P(r\geq c)$ and to get this I would apply the above, i.e. $0.05=P(r\geq c)=P(\frac{r}{s/\sqrt{S_{xx}}}\geq\frac{c}{s/\sqrt{S_{xx}}})$. Since $\frac{r}{s/\sqrt{S_{xx}}}$ is t-distributed I can find the critical value

Comment: and then solve for c. In other words the critical value is calculated in terms of the t-distribution?

Comment: Yes, that is generally how one uses a test statistic. Although it should be noted that the expression for the t statistic should have the estimated *regression* coefficient in the numerator, not the *correlation* coefficient. $\frac{\hat{\beta_1}}{s/\sqrt{s_{xx}}}$ is the quantity which is t-distributed under the null. Try and see if you can do a similar manipulation to the above, using the fact that $r = \hat{\beta_1}\sqrt{\frac{s_{xx}}{s_{yy}}}$ to find a critical value for $r$.

Comment: Do you know a book that explains that? All my books just state the test statistic without any justfication such as above.

Comment: We used "Modern Mathematical Statistics with Applications" for our course on statistical methods. If I recall correctly, most of the results are derived from scratch here.

Comment: Thank you, I'll have look!